# Where to find Adapter for E-11 or E-14 to E-26 light socket

Tags: lighting, halogen, light-fixture

I used to be able to by 200W Halogens for standard fixtures locally.  These were great for my porchlight (which could take the heat), because they lit my entire yard without me having to install more lights or replace the fixture.

I haven't been able to find 200W Halogens lately for standard (E-26) fixtures, but I have found them for both E11 and E14.  Is there an adapter which can be used to adapt these to a standard socket?  Is there anything (other than the heat) which I should worry about in using the E11 or E14 this way?

Comment: What is a "standard light socket" where you are? There are numerous different designs which are considered standard in different places.

Comment: I am assuming (because his profile lists Georgia) that he is referring to a standard "medium base" edison socket (e26/e27).

Comment: @James, it doesn't say which Georgia (there are more than one). Assumption is the mother of all stuff-ups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can buy 250W Medium Base PAR38 bulbs at [1000bulbs](http://www.1000bulbs.com/category/250-watt-par38-halogen-light-bulbs/).

You should be able to [find the adapter](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=e14+e26+adapter#q=e14+e26%7Ce27+adapter&hl=en&safe=active&prmd=ivns&source=univ&tbs=shop:1&tbo=u&ei=0clSTc77GYKglAfQteCZCg&sa=X&oi=product_result_group&ct=title&resnum=3&ved=0CEQQrQQwAg&fp=d4782e148cd670a8) relatively easily online if you still want to go that route.

Comment: Those are directional floods, I am looking for less directional lighting.

Comment: James, could you post where you found the adapters?

Comment: http://www.1000bulbs.com/product/5831/SOCK-92321.html (that particular model is for E14 -> E26)